# How can I bind a SecureString or char[] parameter in .NET Core without using strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When storing a string that is secret (eg a password or key) it is bad practice to use a `System.String` as strings are immutable and you cannot schedule garbage collection to remove them from memory. Microsoft recommends using `SecureString` to avoid this, where the content is also encrypted at rest. See [MSDN: System.Security.SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx)

I cannot see a way of binding a `SecureString` parameter in a .NET Core Controller, the framework throws a `JsonSerializationException` for the parameter when doing the model mapping with an inner exception message of   `Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Security.SecureString.` So the JSON parser has already made a `string` from it, and the secret resides unencrypted in memory.

The framework can't bind even a `char[]`, which is a common workaround for dealing with secret strings (though not encrypted, `char[]` are mutable so can be overwritten to remove them from memory). It fails with a similar exception.

Comment: Isn't is a bit pointless in this situation as the string will already be in memory before any model binding has happened?

Comment: `SecureString` can only be realistically used in a small number of scenarios, where applications can fully control their use of unencrypted secrets. This is not one of them. Guarding against an attacker who can read memory is *hard*. You're typically better off ensuring the secret remains encrypted for a long as possible, for example by not transmitting passwords in serialized JSON in the first place (but only hashes, or otherwise encrypted values). Beyond that you have to consider the trade-offs between securing a machine's memory, and securing the machine itself.

Comment: SecureString is not secure; it is simply an inconvenience to an attacker, not a barrier. Frankly you'd need to be very very clear about what attack vector you're trying to protect yourself from, because realisitically: SecureString doesn't actually save you much : in most scenarios where it is useful, you're already completely owned

Comment: Also SecureString is tightly coupled to windows. At least I remember a GitHub issue around the .NET core release, stating that `SecureString` is implemented for linux (as in behaves as expected) but doesn't use any encryption, so it only use the encryption on windows.Dunno if that changed though. But yes, its very limited where you can use it. One usage scenario are desktop applications where the user can enter a password into a text field and keep it in there, encrypted inmemory until its used. It would return a string to pass it to the API and then clear the strings memory upon usage

Comment: There, that's the GitHub issue on [SecureString](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1387) and current [code and implementation for Unix](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/v2.1.0/src/mscorlib/shared/System/Security/SecureString.Unix.cs#L12-L19) proofs that encryption isn't implemented, so the usage in .NET Core is quite limited, unless you host it on Windows machine. The main point for SecureString were two: Possibility to read it from configuraiton file, encrypted and only decrypt it before using it and then free/zero out the memory.

Comment: Mostly for reasons that it doesn't appear in dumps, like it may be the case if you store the string password in some global configuration file. The ConfigurationManager isn't commonly used on .NET Core and ASP.NET Core, since it was superseded by appsettings.json. For an attacker which has direct access to your machine its useless, because a private certificate on the machine running the application was used to decrypt it and an attacker who has control of the machine would also have control of that certificate and its password too

Comment: @DavidG is correct. There's no point to doing this as the string is *already* in memory. Honestly, the cases where you could *realistically* use and actually benefit from `SecureString` are so limited as to make it almost pointless. The secret would pretty much have to only exists in your code and *only* as a `SecureString` from start to finish. The largest majority of the time, it would be far better to have your secret in some external store, where it can be encrypted, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping that someone would say "Yes, the requests are parsed in native code and you can avoid the values entering managed heap by... {some solution, maybe involving `SecureString`}".

From the comments it sounds like requests are handled in managed code, so one can argue that there is little point using a `SecureString` or `char[]` as the values are already in the heap.

It may still be worth encrypting the values at rest because the garbage collection will evict the strings at some point, just not in a deterministic manner.