# How to solve Heap inspection vulnerability for ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, abp, checkmarx

Checkmarx reported a Heap inspection vulnerability regarding having a string for a Password property.
This bindproperty is part of a PageModel, which gets bound a login form.
Is there a way in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages to use anything else other than regular string to bind password from the form?
The source codes is from [ResetPassword.cshtml.cs](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/account/src/Volo.Abp.Account.Web/Pages/Account/ResetPassword.cshtml.cs)

```
[Required]
[BindProperty]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[DynamicStringLength(typeof(IdentityUserConsts), nameof(IdentityUserConsts.MaxPasswordLength))]
[DisableAuditing]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: Checkmarx expects you to use SecureString type for storing sensitive values such as passwords, but here's a link to an SO post that you may find useful which argues why it wouldn't be an absolute fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797241/how-can-i-bind-a-securestring-or-char-parameter-in-net-core-without-using-str

Comment: many people doesn't see it as a vulnerability